# How to get a plain object in lodash?

Tags: lodash

Is there an elegant way to convert an object that contains prototypes to an object with properties only? (all prototype methods would be omitted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one line:

```
_.omit(myObj, _.isFunction);
```

Also with JSON:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObj));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yh2utkdw/1/